# How can I change the bone axis without using the Roll?

Tags: bones, axis

If I use the "Roll" option from the properties tab, the Z Axis will always face downwards, which will lead to other problems in a game engine.
I've added a picture with my desired result.

What won't work:

- Mirroring *Edit Mode > Mirror*, tested along all axis
- Mirroring then scaling towards the Y-Axis to keep the axis constellation

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: rotate it 180° around its X axis so that it points towards the opposite direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the bone to stay the way it is but change axis orientation, use Ctrl-Period, and set it manually.